# How to close a showmodeldialog window from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, modal-dialog

I am opening the window like this

```
 var MyArgs = new Array(ParmA, ParmB, ParmC, ParmD, ParmE, ParmF);
var leftpost = getWindow_TotalWidth() - 1000 - 100;
var WinSettings1 = "dialogHeight:580px; dialogWidth:950px;edge:Raised; center:Yes; resizable:No; status: No;dialogLeft:" + leftpost + ";dialogTop:253px";
var MyArgs = window.showModalDialog("../Accounts/LedgerAdd.aspx?LedgerCode=" + MyArgs[1].toString().split("~")[0] + "&Popup=1", MyArgs, WinSettings1);
```

I would like to close the window based on condition. I have tried so many ways like

```
  If Not Convert.ToDecimal(HidOpeningBalance.Value) = Convert.ToDecimal(TxtOpeningBalance.Text) Then
            Dim LedgerID As Integer = Request.QueryString("LedgerCode")
            Dim dtTransactionCount As DataTable = Grid.GetDataTable("sp_checkForAnyTransaction", LedgerID)
            If dtTransactionCount.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                LblError.Text = "You can not change Opening Balance after transactions made on this ledger."

                Exit Sub
            Else
                Call FnUpdate()
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "Javascript", "javascript:CloseWindow();", True)

            End If
        Else
            LblError.Text = ""
            Call FnUpdate()
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "Javascript", "javascript:window.close();", True)
            'Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>self.close();</script>")

            'Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "Javascript", "javascript:CloseWindow();", True)

        End If
```

my closeWindows function is

```
  function CloseWindow() {
        window.close();         
    }
```

If I call the function on **onClientClick event, the popup is closing.** But if I try to close it from code behind, the window is not closing. I have tried those three ways(I have commented in my code).

Answer (score 1):

Please review this solution in the link provided.
http://forums.asp.net/t/993380.aspx?Close+Window+that+opens+with+window+showModalDialog
as you will see the solution became:

```
<base target="_self">
```